# Add svn-ignore property for all subfolders in SVN 1.7

Tags: svn, svnignore

Now that Subversion 1.7 is storing all metadata centralized at the checkout root, I was wondering if there's a way to set an ignore on the lines of `**/.classpath` which ignores the ".classpath" folder in all subfolders (much like you can set in .git-ignore)

Please note I know how to use svn propedit, and make bash scripts. What I am looking for, however, is a global approach like git's rather than a script I can run for every new project.

Regarding duplicates:I can't find any question that seems modern enough to encompass svn 1.7, hence the potential duplicate.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. 1.7 change **nothing** in global-ignore pattern usage
2. You have to re-read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html) and understand usage of `global-ignores` key

Damn, run 'svn propset -R svn:ignore ...' in the root of trunk-WC isn't *impossible hard* job when you starting new project with initial tree

Comment: As I understand it, running your command will destroy all previous ignores in my repo, and replace them with the ones I put there. Furthermore, everytime I add a project I'll have to add the files, delete the ones I want to ignore, and then run the ignore. Like I said, I already have a script to do that, but it is not nearly as useful as a global git-ignore. I'll check the `global-ignores`! Thanks!

Comment: @Miquel - when I said about recursive propset, I said about new projects with empty tree **only**

Comment: Ah I see! Could you add that to your answer? I'm just worried someone looses something by not realising the context you meant. And thanks for answering!